# In React How to select multiple values from enum in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, enums

I want multiple select checkbox option for enum value. Now i can select only one value from dropdown

```
 <ValidatedField
                label="flowers Type"
                id="flowers_type"
                name="flowers_type"
                data-cy="flowers_type"
                type="select"
              >
                {flowersTypeValues.map(flowersType => (
                  <option value={flowersType} key={flowersType}>
                    {flowersType}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </ValidatedField>
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code for better understanding and screenshots of what is currently appearing and what is that you are expecting

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-benji-7vbj2h?file=/src/App.js Please have a look at this

Comment: I have used dummy data for `flowersTypesValues` for now, FYI. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `React-select` which allows you to select multiple options.

`React-select` gives you various options to customize it as you want You can look at the documentation below.

https://react-select.com/home#getting-started

**To Install:**

`npm i --save react-select`

here is a basic **example** of it:

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';

const colourOptions =  [
  { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
  { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#FF5630', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
  { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' },
  { value: 'green', label: 'Green', color: '#36B37E' },
  { value: 'forest', label: 'Forest', color: '#00875A' },
  { value: 'slate', label: 'Slate', color: '#253858' },
  { value: 'silver', label: 'Silver', color: '#666666' },
];

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
);
```